# detail disclosure with number

Tags: iphone

is it possible to implement a detail disclosure button on a table view cell that displays the number of items in that category or do i need to make a custom cell for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard way for that. *Maybe* you can get along with a custom view for the number and set it as the accessory view for the cell.